# Deprecated T-SQL Syntax

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is quoting every part of a SELECT statement deprecated T-SQL syntax?

```
SELECT "A", "B", "C" FROM "database"."table" where "column" = @p2
```

This is syntax being used by MS Access to query against a SQL Server instance.  I do not know what version of Access is being used.

Comment: I haven't seen that in any of the sql code I've worked on before. I'm not sure if it's depreciated but at least not widely practiced syntax

Comment: are you talking about sql server 2012?

Comment: This is standard SQL quoting. Why should it be deprecated? (But then it's Microsoft...)

Comment: The only problem is the "database"."table", I tihnk it won't work. You should use "table" only or "database"."shema"."table".

Comment: Whether this works depends on your QUOTED_IDENTIFIER setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it is not. Microsoft SQL 2012 still supports using double quotes in select statements see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This sentence is working, BUT only if A, B and C are columns:

```
SELECT "A", "B", "C" FROM "database"."table" where "column" = @p2
```

If those are values like varchar, you have to use 'A','B','C'.

And the "database"."table" is not well defined.

It should be `"database"."schemaName"."table"`. (Usually schemaName is dbo)

So the query is working on this way:

```
 SELECT "A", "B", "C" FROM "database"."schemaName"."table" where "column" = @p2
```

OR simply use

```
SELECT "A", "B", "C" FROM "table" where "column" = @p2
```